# Sklearn custom transformers with pipeline: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, hyperparameters

I am learning about `sklearn` custom transformers and read about the two core ways to create custom transformers:

1. by setting up a custom class that inherits from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`, or
2. by creating a transformation method and passing it to `FunctionTransformer`.

I wanted to compare these two approaches by implementing a "meta-vectorizer" functionality: a vectorizer that supports either `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` and transforms the input data according to the specified vectorizer type.

However, I can't seem to get any of the two work when passing them to a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. I am getting the following error message in the `fit_transform()` step:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match 
exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 6 and the array 
at index 1 has size 1
```

My code for option 1 (using a custom class):

```
class Vectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, vectorizer:Callable=CountVectorizer(), ngram_range:tuple=(1,1)) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.vectorizer = vectorizer
        self.ngram_range = ngram_range
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_vect_ = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(X.copy())
        return X_vect_.toarray()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('column_transformer', ColumnTransformer([
        ('lesson_type_category', OneHotEncoder(), ['Type']),
        ('comment_text_vectorizer', Vectorizer(), ['Text'])],
        remainder='drop')),
    ('model', LogisticRegression())])

param_dict = {'column_transformer__comment_text_vectorizer__vectorizer': \
[CountVectorizer(), TfidfVectorizer()]
}

randsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_dict, cv=2, scoring='f1',).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And my code for option 2 (creating a custom transformer from a function using `FunctionTransformer`):

```
def vectorize_text(X, vectorizer: Callable):
    X_vect_ = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
    return X_vect_.toarray()

vectorizer_transformer = FunctionTransformer(vectorize_text, kw_args={'vectorizer': TfidfVectorizer()})

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('column_transformer', ColumnTransformer([
        ('lesson_type_category', OneHotEncoder(), ['Type']),
        ('comment_text_vectorizer', vectorizer_transformer, ['Text'])],
        remainder='drop')),
    ('model', LogisticRegression())])

param_dict = {'column_transformer__comment_text_vectorizer__kw_args': \
    [{'vectorizer':CountVectorizer()}, {'vectorizer': TfidfVectorizer()}]
}

randsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_dict, cv=2, scoring='f1').fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Imports and sample data:

```
import pandas as pd 
from typing import Callable
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A99', 'hi i love python very much', 'c', 1],
    ['B07', 'which programming language should i learn', 'b', 0],
    ['A12', 'what is the difference between python django flask', 'b', 1],
    ['A21', 'i want to be a programmer one day', 'c', 0],
    ['B11', 'should i learn java or python', 'b', 1],
    ['C01', 'how much can i earn as a programmer with python', 'a', 0]
], columns=['Src', 'Text', 'Type', 'Target'])
```

### Notes:

- As recommended [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179217/sklearn-pipeline-all-the-input-array-dimensions-for-the-concatenation-axis-must), I transformed all sparse matrices to dense arrays after the vectorization, as you can see in both cases: `X_vect_.toarray()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that both `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer` require their input to be 1D (and not 2D). In such cases the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) of `ColumnTransformer` states that parameter `columns` of the `transformers` tuple should be passed as a *string* rather than as a list.

> columns: str, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable

> Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, while strings can reference DataFrame columns by name. ***A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer.*** A callable is passed the input data X and can return any of the above. To select multiple columns by name or dtype, you can use make_column_selector.

Therefore, the following will work in your case (i.e. changing `['Text']` into `'Text'`).

```
class Vectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, vectorizer:Callable=CountVectorizer(), ngram_range:tuple=(1,1)) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.vectorizer = vectorizer
        self.ngram_range = ngram_range
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_vect_ = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(X.copy())
        return X_vect_.toarray()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('column_transformer', ColumnTransformer([
        ('lesson_type_category', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), ['Type']),
        ('comment_text_vectorizer', Vectorizer(), 'Text')], remainder='drop')),
    ('model', LogisticRegression())])

param_dict = {'column_transformer__comment_text_vectorizer__vectorizer': [CountVectorizer(), TfidfVectorizer()]
}

randsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_dict, cv=2, scoring='f1',).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can adjust the example with `FunctionTransformer` accordingly. Observe, as a final remark, that I had to pass `handle_unknown='ignore'` to `OneHotEncoder` to prevent the possibility that an error would have arisen in case of unknown categories seen during the test phase of your cross-validation (and not seen during the training phase).