# Vectorize only text column and standardize numeric column using pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline, transformer-model

I am trying to vectorize the text column and then standardize the numeric column. Following are the python scripts:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer


numeric_features = ["sklearn_cosine_similarity"] # numeric feature

categorical_features = ["clean_text"] # text feature
categorical_transformer = CountVectorizer()

preprocess = make_column_transformer((CountVectorizer(), categorical_features),(StandardScaler(), numeric_features))

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("vect", preprocess),
        ("knnr", KNeighborsRegressor())
    ]
)

parameters = {
    "vect__countvectorizer__max_features" : [None, 50,100],
    "vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range" : [(1, 1)],  # unigrams
    "knnr__n_neighbors" : [3,4,5],
    "knnr__weights" :['uniform', 'distance'],
    "knnr__leaf_size" :[20],
    'knnr__metric' : ['euclidean']
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, verbose=4,scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',cv=3)

grid_search.fit(X_train[['clean_text','sklearn_cosine_similarity']].values, y_train.values)
```

`type(X_train[['clean_text','sklearn_cosine_similarity']]) is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

`type(y_train) is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Getting following errors while running the fit,

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 18 candidates, totalling 54 fits
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=3, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=4, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=uniform, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=None, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=50, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/3] END knnr__leaf_size=20, knnr__metric=euclidean, knnr__n_neighbors=5, knnr__weights=distance, vect__countvectorizer__max_features=100, vect__countvectorizer__ngram_range=(1, 1); total time=   0.0s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    373         try:
--> 374             all_columns = X.columns
    375         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9996/3908756850.py in <module>
      1 from time import time
      2 t0 = time()
----> 3 grid_search.fit(X_train[['clean_text','sklearn_cosine_similarity']].values, y_train.values)
      4 print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    878             refit_start_time = time.time()
    879             if y is not None:
--> 880                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    881             else:
    882                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    339         """
    340         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 341         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    342         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    343                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    301                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    302             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 303             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    304                 cloned_transformer, X, y, None,
    305                 message_clsname='Pipeline',

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    752     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    753         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 754             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    755         else:
    756             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    504         self._validate_transformers()
    505         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 506         self._validate_remainder(X)
    507 
    508         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    330         cols = []
    331         for columns in self._columns:
--> 332             cols.extend(_get_column_indices(X, columns))
    333 
    334         remaining_idx = sorted(set(range(self._n_features)) - set(cols))

~\anaconda3\envs\deepai\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    374             all_columns = X.columns
    375         except AttributeError:
--> 376             raise ValueError("Specifying the columns using strings is only "
    377                              "supported for pandas DataFrames")
    378         if isinstance(key, str):

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

if more details required then please let me know.

**Please do not delete this question as I have not found any similar question.**
**if duplicate question is there then please refer the link.**

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue within your code is related to the definition of your `ColumnTransformer` via `make_column_transformer`. It refers to parameter `columns` of the `transformers` tuple. According to the [docs of `ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) (or equivalently to the [docs of `make_column_transformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html)):

> columns : str, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable
>
> Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, while ***strings can reference DataFrame columns by name***. ***A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer***. A callable is passed the input data X and can return any of the above. To select multiple columns by name or dtype, you can use make_column_selector..

Indeed, on one side, when fitting the `GridSearchCV` instance on numpy arrays (you're calling `.values()` on `X_train` and `y_train`) you should better reference columns positionally (i.e. via integers) according to the docs above. In other terms, you're violating the fact that you can refer to columns via names - i.e. with strings or list of strings - only when fitting a DataFrame directly (*strings can* ***ONLY*** *reference DataFrame columns by name*).

On the other side, you should take care of the fact that `CountVectorizer()` requires its input to be 1D and not 2D. In such a case the documentation states  that you should refer to columns in your DataFrame via strings (`'clean_text'`) rather than array-like of strings (eg list of strings) as you're doing in `categorical_features` (`['clean_text']`).

Therefore if you want to keep on referring to columns by name in your `ColumnTransformer` definition I would suggest to define `categorical_features` as `categorical_features = 'clean_text'` and fitting the dataframe directly in `grid_search.fit()`.

I would also suggest the following post dealing with a similar issue:

- [Sklearn custom transformers with pipeline: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550018/sklearn-custom-transformers-with-pipeline-all-the-input-array-dimensions-for-th/70550548#70550548)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you don't pass a dataframe to fit but just a numpy array, see
`X_train[['clean_text','sklearn_cosine_similarity']].values` where values just extracts the underlying numpy array. Try to remove `.values`

Comment: getting below error when using as pandas dataframe **ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 72**