# sklearn .fit transformers , IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm using a "ColumnTransformer" even though I'm transforming only one feature because I don't know how else to change only the "clean_text" feature. I am not using a "make_column_transformer" with a "make_column_selector" because I would like to use a gridsearch later but I don't understand why I can't find column 0 of the dataset

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#dataset download: https://www.kaggle.com/saurabhshahane/twitter-sentiment-dataset 

df = pd.read_csv('Twitter_Data.csv')
y = df1['category']   #target
X = df1['clean_text'].values.astype('U') #feature, i transformed "X" into a string even if in theory it was because otherwise it would return an error

transformers = [
    ['text_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(), [0]];
]

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers, remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit(X) #<---IndexError: tuple index out of range
X = ct.transform(X)
```

Comment: Please always provide the full error traceback.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be the culprit, but usually the transformers should be given as a tuple, not a list: `(text_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(), [0])` (and I don't know what the semicolon was doing there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo there are a couple of points to be highlighted on this example:

- `CountVectorizer` requires its input to be 1D. In such cases, documentation for [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) states that

> columns: str, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable
>
> Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, while strings can reference DataFrame columns by name. ***A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector)***, otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer.

Therefore, the `columns` parameter should be passed as an *int* rather than as a *list of int*. I would also suggest [Sklearn custom transformers with pipeline: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550018/sklearn-custom-transformers-with-pipeline-all-the-input-array-dimensions-for-th/70550548#70550548) for another reference.

- Given that you're using a column transformer, I would pass the whole dataframe to method `.fit()` called on the `ColumnTransformer` instance, rather than `X` only.
- The dataframe seems to have missing values; it might be convenient to process them somehow. For instance, by dropping them and applying what is described above I was able to make it work, but you can also decide to proceed differently.

  ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

   #dataset download: https://www.kaggle.com/saurabhshahane/twitter-sentiment-dataset 
   df = pd.read_csv('Twitter_Data.csv')
   y = df['category']  
   X = df['clean_text']

   df.info()

   df_n = df.dropna()

   transformers = [
       ('text_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(), 0)
   ]

   ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers, remainder='passthrough')

   ct.fit(df_n) 
   ct.transform(df_n)
  ```
- As specified within the comments, `transformers` should be specified as a *list of tuples* (as per the documentation) rather than as *list of lists*. However, running the snippet above with your `transformers` specification seems to work. I've eventually observed that substituting tuples with lists elsewhere (in unrelated pieces of code I have) seems not to raise issues. However, as per my experience, it is for sure more common to find them passed as *list of tuples*.

Comment: Your solution is working but if i print "df_n" the whole data is exactly the same as before the vectorization

Comment: Not sure I get your point; you should look at the output of `ct.transform(df_n)` to see how data has been transformed after the application of `CountVectorizer()` on the first column of the original dataset.

Comment: With "ct.transform (df_n)" it gives me the statistic of the dataset, but if i print the dataset shouldn't it return the 'clean_text' column as numbers? to train the model with?

Comment: Actually, it does. Perhaps the misunderstanding comes from the fact that it might return a sparse matrix. To get the dataset back as a numpy array try typing `ct.transform(df_n).toarray()` (and eventually reassign it back to df_n if needed)